# Rails: dropdown menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, menu

Environment: Rails 3.2.3

I am editing this question to include the helper module's source code, and the suggestions here:

This is my first attempt at doing a dropdown menu in a Rails application. I tried looking for help on the topic, but what complicated things is that the term dropdown menu is used for actual dropdown menu (page menu), as well as what is dropdown lists, form options, form selections, etc. in questions,and forums, making it difficult to find the information I'm looking for.

I found a pointer to https://github.com/dkeskar/rails-jquery-dropdown, (source code at end of post) and following the instructions, I downloaded jquery_dropdown_helper.rb: ) and placed it in /lib

In my Gemfile, I have the following:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

In _header.html.erb, I have the following:

```
<% require 'jquery_dropdown_helper' %>
....
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort_criteria %>
<%= dropdown_tags :sort_criteria, 'Select Criteria',
    %w(Category Status Amount-High Amount-Low) %>
```

But this is not working. Here's the error code I'm getting:

```
undefined method `gsub' for :sort_criteria:Symbol
```

I looked at the trace, and it seems as if this line in jquery_dropdown_helper.rb is the issue:

```
id = options[:id] || "#{field.gsub(/[[]\s]/, '-')}-selector"
```

Any ideas?

## SOLUTION TO THE DROPDOWN MENU ISSUE

I was looking for a way to have dropdown menus in my rails applications, but could not get an answer to this question. Following a couple of days of research, I did find a solution, using the Twitter gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'.

Add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
```

Add the following to your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

Make sure it's in this exact order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

Then, where you want the dropdown menu, add the following:

```
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="dropdown" id="admin_menu">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#admin_menu">
                ADMIN
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <% Admin_menu.each do |menu_text,menu_action| %>
                    <li><a href=" <%= menu_action %>"><%= menu_text %></a></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
```

Note that I have the following hash:

```
Admin_menu = Hash.new
Admin_menu["Events"] = "events#index"
Admin_menu["Categories"] = "categories#index"
Admin_menu["Panels"] = "panels#index"
```

Assuming that you have scaffolding for the following: events, categories, and panels, it should all work

Comment: Did you ever define sort_criteria?

Comment: It's defined in jquery_dropdown_helper.rb pointed to by the link in my question

Comment: nope... double-check the source

Comment: Please see the discussion in the second answer: hidden_field_tag is a Rails helper method allowing me to add sort_criteria as a form element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery_dropdown_helper.rb does not provide a method called sort_criteria. I think the example should be:

```
<% require 'jquery_dropdown_helper' %>
....
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort_criteria %>
<%= dropdown_tags :sort_criteria, 'Select Criteria',
    %w(Category Status Amount-High Amount-Low) %>
```

:sort_criteria is just the name of the form element and can be a symbol or a string (i.e. :sort_criteria or 'sort_criteria')

Comment: Yes, of course, I added the comment too fast. hidden_field_tag is a Rails helper method that allows me to add a field to the Request, in this case sort_criteria.

I made the modification you suggested (adding :), but now I'm getting the following error:

undefined method `gsub' for :sort_criteria:Symbol

Comment: I looked at the trace, and it seems as if this line in jquery_dropdown_helper.rb is the issue: id = options[:id] || "#{field.gsub(/[\[\]\s]/, '-')}-selector"

Comment: This cannot be a symbol, because gsub is not going on a symbol. As a string, it does work, but the actual library that I downloaded, does not work. Instead of the dropdown menu I was expecting to see, I got the following: <a id="admin_menu_selection-selector" class="fg-button fg-button-icon-right ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default" href="#admin_menu_selection-selector-items" tabindex="0" > <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Admin</a> ....................